# Is there any optimised algorithm to calculate 2D fourier transform

Tags: image-processing, fourier-transform

I m trying to implement my own code for finding the 2D fourier transform of an image in MATLAB using the formula for it, but it take toooo much time to come up with the answer, is there a defined fast fourier algorithm for 2D FT, which I can study and optimize my code.

Comment: The fast FFT libraries are created using hand-optimized C and assembly language for each particular CPU ISA.  See the source code for fftw.  It's a non-trivial optimization.  If you are using a DFT formula, instead of small prime factorization, it will be orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: How can I access the codes of fftw?

Comment: GPL Open Source code that is available on the web.  Search.

Comment: Notice that fftw in fact is code to generate the optimized code. And that is even nor non-trivial. The fftw, which Matlab uses internally, is really blazingly fast. Either your pictures are impossibly large, you're using it incorrectly, or something else is taking up your CPU time. I recommend actually using the profiler built into the current versions of MATLAB. It gives a very nice perspective on where your time is actually spent. Hint: in my experience, it's almost never the fft that's actually to blame.

Comment: @hotpaw2 it's actually not GPL,iirc, but some MIT or BSD license that is free for non-commercial use.

Comment: I had written my own code for 2d dft, that was taking time, not MATLAB function

Comment: Yeah, well, don't do something like that. The fft in MATLAB, I'm almost certain, can also be used for 2D ffts

Comment: If not directly, than, in any case, first row-wise, then column-wise: the 2D-DFT is separable.

Comment: Yeah, I actually rearranged the equation in matrix form and now its able to get the result in 24 secs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FFT uses an optimized algorithm for doing a DFT computation.  The FFT is O(NLogN) instead of O(N^2) for a naive DFT or basis matrix multiply, thus potentially much faster for large N, and is easiest to implement (if you are coding it yourself) when N breaks down into only very small primes, such as 2.

You can use multiple passes of a 1D FFT (first rows, then columns) to implement a 2D FFT.

Comment: `x = magic(6);

X=[];Y=[];

for i=1:6
    X(i,:) = dit(x(i,:));
end
X = X(:,1:6);
for i=1:6
    Y(:,i) = dit(X(:,i).');
end
Z = fft2(x);
imagesc(abs(Y));figure();imagesc(abs(Z));`
I have written this code for computing the 2d FFT, where dit() is my own function written for decimation in time.The output is somewhat same as that of matlab fft2(). The difference is most probably because of the 0's that are appened in the DIT algorithm to make the length in power of 2. Any suggestion on how to improve that.Thanks :)

Comment: Don't use your own decimation in time and zero padding function. Don't apply functions with a for loop. Get used to proper MATLAB "matrix-vector product" thinking

Comment: You are assuming the OPs class (or self-learn) assignment wasn't to write, test, and benchmark their own DIT and 2D decomposition routines.

Comment: Yes, because otherwise op would basically be asking us to improve his homework without saying it's his homework or without explaining his design and post his code in the question itself. And that is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Different breeds of the FFT (fast Fourier transform) can be used, as [answered by @hotpaw2](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/45727/15892). However, the pure "number of operations" count is not sufficient anymore, as:

- the cost of operations is not anymore directly related to the number of $+,-,\times,/$
- pipelines, multi-threads, GPU, etc. are hardware deal changers
- for huge data, data transfer is becoming more a bottleneck than the mere algorithmic cost
- for fixed-size data (like $16\times16$ blocks), some customized algorithms are more efficient than the standard FFT (I don't have FFT ones in mind, but some of the DCT, or discrete cosine transform)
- for some data structures, like sparse data, you can get faster approximate Fourier algorithms.